# Trying to solve merge confilct using Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, merge-conflict-resolution

I am taking an online course learning Git for the first time. In the course, the instructor is using P4merge as a difftool and mergetool. However, I am using Visual Studio Code. Using Visual Studio Code as a difftool works fine but it won't work as a mergetool. I have been searching all over the web for an answer but no luck.

[This is a screenshot of what happens in my terminal when I call mergetool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slNJG.png).

Instead of opening Visual Studio Code, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS users:

`code` is not in your PATH, so when git is trying to execute VSCode with the command `code` it can't find it.
To solve this, open VSCode, open command palette (⇧ + ⌘ + p) , and type:
`Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`
Than hit enter and give it permissions to install.
This will install `code` to your PATH and will solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you added in your gitconfig the following config

```
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait $MERGED
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

The error you getting about `command not found` is because you didn't export the vscode binary to your $PATH. Try to do something like (I'm using Mac)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/
```

and you should be able to use `git mergetool` opening in Vscode.